# Laravel - Form action url Not Found & PUT method not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working in Laravel 5.2, and using the Eloquent ORM for dealing with Database. I tried to update user data in database but when I click on my `UPDATE` button it gives me the error below. I am using the `PUT` method for updating the data in database as per Laravel REST rules.

**Error URL :**

> http://localhost/users?_token=wazgR1tQaznQwRdejXdx4g3jLgbtlfPLIeIiXdRy&name=warka&email=&password=

**Error:**

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

**User Controller:**

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view('create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:5'

        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('http://localhost/laravelking/users/create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
         }else{
            User::create(array(
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            ));
            return Redirect::to('http://localhost/laravelking/users');
        }

    }

    public function index(){
        return view::make('users')->withUsers(User::all());
    }
    public function show($id){
        $user = User::find($id);

        if($user == null){
            return Redirect::to('http://localhost/laravelking/users');
        }else{
            return View::make('profile')->withUser($user);
        }
        return 'list '.$id;
    }
    public function update($id){
        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'required|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:5'

        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return Redirect::to('http://localhost/laravelking/users/'.$id.'/edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
         }else{
            $user = User::find($id);
            if(Input::has('name')) $user->name = Input::get('name');
            if(Input::has('email')) $user->email = Input::get('email');
            if(Input::has('password')) $user->password = Input::get('password');
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('http://localhost/laravelking/users/'.$id);
        }
    }
    public function edit($id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        if($user == null){
            return Redirect::to('http://localhost/laravelking/users');
        }else{
            return View::make('edit')->with('id',$id);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        return 'list'.$id;
    }
}
```

**View Update Form  :**

```
<form role="form" method="PUT" action="users/".$id>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">New Name:</label>
    <input type="username" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">New Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">New Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
</form>
```

**Profile VIEW From Where I enter to update View is :**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1> Hello {!! $user->name !!}</h1>
            <h3> Your Email is {!! $user->email !!}</h3>
            <h3 style="color:red"> Your Password is {!! $user->password !!}</h3>
            <h1> {!! Html::link('users/'.$user->id.'/edit','Edit ') !!}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Route :**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
    Route::resource('users','UsersController');
});
```

**Updated :**

Just changed the Form Method to : 
`<form role="form" action='http://localhost/laravelking/users/<?php echo $id; ?>' method="PUT">`

I.e $id to PHP echo and it worked but data in DB is not updated !

The New URL now looks like this:

```
http://localhost/laravelking/users/1?_token=wazgR1tQaznQwRdejXdx4g3jLgbtlfPLIeIiXdRy&name=Lololololol&email=Lololololol%40gaic.com&password=Lololololol
```

But problem is data is not updated in DB

Comment: How does your routes file look like? If he doesn't find the requested page this should be a missing or wrong route.

Comment: yes but the routes are still wrong if you get an 404 Error from `http://localhost/users/4/users?_token=wazgR1tQaznQwRdejXdx4g3jLgbtlfPLIeIiXdRy&name=John+Doe&email=john%40gmail.com&password=john1234` then this means`http://localhost/users/4/users` doesn't even exist. Which means it can't find a route for that. This is not a Laravel error, the 404 comes from your browser saying that it can't find the requested URL.

Comment: @Peh that's not the problem buddy can you take a deeper look !
Thanks

Comment: can you show your routes for the `Users` update in your question

Comment: @Qazi check I have updated the question!

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing **"laravelking"** in your url? `http://localhost/laravelking/users?_token=...`

Comment: @iivannov I just changed <form role="form" action='http://localhost/laravelking/users/<?php echo $id; ?>' method="PUT"> I.e $id to PHP echo and it worked but data in DB is not updated !
The New URL now looks like this:http://localhost/laravelking/users/1?_token=wazgR1tQaznQwRdejXdx4g3jLgbtlfPLIeIiXdRy&name=Lololololol&email=Lololololol%40gaic.com&password=Lololololol

But problem is data is not updated in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is in the *laravelking* directory, but your form is sending the request just to *http://localhost*.

You better change your form action to something like this:

```
 <form action="{{url('users/' . $id)}}" ... >
```

---

Because HTML forms does not support PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods you need to add an additional field to make this work:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Or you can use some of the Laravel helpers for this:

```
// Plain PHP
echo method_field('PUT'); 

//Blade template engine
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

You can read more about this here: [Laravel HTTP Routing - Method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: I am sending request to http://localhost/laravelking/users/<?php echo $id; ?> specific ID Not to Localhost and I tried that hidden field input BUT nothing is updated in database !

Comment: Are you triggering your update method? Is the validation passing? Debug a little and give us more information. Check if there are any validation errors. If you are not changing the name and email the unique validation will fail.

Comment: yes update method ! And I even removed the validation code still it is not updating DB data!

Comment: Just `dd()` the *$user* object after the *find()* method, then after you set the fields and then check what is returned by the save() method and you'll understand where it fails. Also check what sql query is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the help but all I did was just replace the HTML5 Form tag Opening and closing with Blade Template {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'users/'.$id, 'method' => 'put' , 'role' => 'form' )) !!}

//My Form Data with Styles

{!! Form::close() !!}

and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Great! What it does is to put `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">` for you, so it's strange it doesn't work with you manually doing it.